# sqlite : sum of results group by timestamp and interval of 5 minutes

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, group-by, timestamp

I am trying to split last one hour data,last six hours,last six days and six months data.I have seen most of the answers works for MySQL,how to achieve this in sqlite?
I have tried with this sqlite query:

```
SELECT timestamp,usage FROM network_band WHERE timestamp <= '2017-08-17 10:57:26' and timestamp >= '2017-08-17 09:57:26'  and mac='68:c4:4d:8b:65:dd' GROUP BY strftime('%H:%M:%S 00:00:00', timestamp, '+5 minutes')
```

**results what i got:**

```
"2017-08-17 10:30:26"   "0.00208962886"
"2017-08-17 10:30:32"   "0.02299923714"
"2017-08-17 10:30:35"   "0.18050153"
"2017-08-17 10:30:38"   "0.761394722"
"2017-08-17 10:30:47"   "9.905705062"
"2017-08-17 10:30:51"   "6.078996"
"2017-08-17 10:30:57"   "11.204719152"
"2017-08-17 10:31:00"   "5.284454384"
"2017-08-17 10:31:06"   "6.86252996"
"2017-08-17 10:31:09"   "3.79881057599999"
"2017-08-17 10:31:12"   "0.798022895999992"
"2017-08-17 10:32:52"   "0.00697107399999197"
"2017-08-17 10:32:55"   "0.0328375519999895"
"2017-08-17 10:32:58"   "0.0226850799999951"
"2017-08-17 10:33:01"   "0.0220522059999979"
"2017-08-17 10:34:08"   "0.0676957600000065"
"2017-08-17 10:34:14"   "0.00304612000000759"
"2017-08-17 10:34:45"   "0.0634264620000096"
"2017-08-17 10:34:51"   "0.038900465999987"
"2017-08-17 10:34:57"   "0.00548396199999957"
"2017-08-17 10:35:21"   "0.0180780599999935"
"2017-08-17 10:35:28"   "0.0658217339999965"
"2017-08-17 10:35:38"   "5.418789222"
"2017-08-17 10:36:38"   "0.000912889999995059"
"2017-08-17 10:36:59"   "0.00126196399999401"
"2017-08-17 10:37:02"   "8.46684473799999"
"2017-08-17 10:37:05"   "4.540849192"
"2017-08-17 10:37:08"   "1.82630219199999"
"2017-08-17 10:37:11"   "0.689901717999987"
"2017-08-17 10:37:20"   "0.000524084000005587"
"2017-08-17 10:37:33"   "0.0693058519999994"
"2017-08-17 10:37:39"   "0.151251209999998"
"2017-08-17 10:37:45"   "3.526737192"
"2017-08-17 10:38:00"   "20.165658744"
"2017-08-17 10:38:06"   "0.00512826599999983"
"2017-08-17 10:38:55"   "0.124861593999995"
"2017-08-17 10:39:01"   "0.258720593999996"
"2017-08-17 10:39:08"   "0.362066363999986"
"2017-08-17 10:39:14"   "0.0221023439999897"
"2017-08-17 10:39:51"   "0.194911001999998"
"2017-08-17 10:40:00"   "0.128526397999991"
"2017-08-17 10:40:12"   "0.0315613979999938"
"2017-08-17 10:40:15"   "0.0247038439999869"
"2017-08-17 10:40:18"   "0.091926603999994"
```

**Desired outuput:**

something like this:

```
**"2017-08-17 10:30:26"   "0.00208962886"
"2017-08-17 10:35:28"   "sum(10:30 to 10:35)"
"2017-08-17 10:40:18"   "sum(10:35 to 10:40)"**
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
GROUP BY strftime('%H:%M:%S 00:00:00', timestamp, '+5 minutes')
```

This moves the timestamp five minutes into the future, but different timestamps still are different timestamps.
But grouping requires that all rows in the group end up with the same value in the GROUP BY clause.

In SQLite, you can do this by converting the timestamp into a number of seconds (`strftime('%s', ...)`), dividing by the number of seconds in the interval, and then rounding (the rounding is implicit with an integer division):

```sql
...
GROUP BY strftime('%s', timestamp) / 6 * 60 * 60   -- six hours
```